# Is the usage of eval() justified here?

Tags: javascript, eval

The JavaScript object `data` has an attribute 'amplitudes' which is a string concatenated bunch of bitmask arrays coming from the server.

```
var data = {
  "amplitudes":           
  "[1,1,1,4,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,4,1,9,1],[1,1,9,1,16,1],[1,32,1,1,1,9],[4,4,4,1,1,1]"
}
```

.

This needs be broken down into six independant arrays. I am using a combination of `split()` and `eval()` to accomplish it in the following way:

```
var amplitudes = [];
amplitudes = data.amplitudes.split("],[");
for(var i=0;i<amplitudes.length;i+=1){
    (i+1)%2>0 ? amplitudes[i] = amplitudes[i] + "]" : amplitudes[i] = "[" + amplitudes[i];
    amplitudes[i] = eval(amplitudes[i]);
}
```

Questions

---

1) Is there a more **elegant** and **efficient** way to do this?? I am not too happy with the usage of eval(), but had a feeling split is more efficient than a regex? I haven't run a benchmark yet.

2) I am also open to manipulating the format in which the field 'amplitudes' is stored in database so that my overall design gets simpler.

Suggestions welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you probably process your data with a server-side language simply make it generate a JavaScript array. If you have an array in your server-side code, use a JSON encoder to build the JavaScript object/array.

```
var data = {
  "amplitudes": [[1,1,1,4,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,4,1,9,1], [1,1,9,1,16,1], [1,32,1,1,1,9], [4,4,4,1,1,1]]
}
```

If you cannot change what you get from the server, you can do it using eval but in a much simpler way:

```
var str = "[1,1,1,4,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,4,1,9,1],[1,1,9,1,16,1],[1,32,1,1,1,9],[4,4,4,1,1,1]";
var arr = eval('[' + str + ']');
```

Comment: Waiting for a while if there is any better answer that might come along, otherwise i will accept yours.

Comment: It is not VERY evil as you don't open a security hole - if it's your data you probably know it's safe.
It is still somehow evil as the proper way would be making your serverside code output a JavaScript array (`json_encode()` if you are using PHP) - if you can avoid eval, avoid it.

Comment: @papdel: Unless I missed something, ThiefMaster recommended using `JSON`.  His `eval()` solution should be used only if you cannot switch to using `JSON`.

Comment: @ Stephen, Thanks! Changed this at server side to send javascript arrays. This avoids eval() and makes the database fields more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the server, just have the "amplitudes" property be an array of arrays, and don't write it out with quotes:

```
var data = {
  amplitudes: [ [1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], ... ]
};
```

Now your client need do no decoding at all.

Comment: I have only one field amplitudes to save all the bitmasks together in the database. 'amplitudes' is one of the many attributes thats being sent over in the json

Comment: Sample Json: {"options":"a,b,c","qs_id":4,"amplitudes":"[1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]",
"requirements":"1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2"}

Comment: You store the "amplitudes" as a *string* like that in the database?  Ugh.

Comment: Anyway, there is no need to quote those values in the JSON.  Just let the array be printed out like that, and the JSON parser will recognize it as an array value.

Answer (score 1):

The eval() function is generally used to decode JSON data that is considered 'safe', as using eval on user-defined data can result in XSS attacks. Anyway, you can make your code more elegant by using regular expressions to match the arrays, then use eval to decode the array components:

```
var matches = data.amplitudes.match(/\[.*?\]/g);
 var amplitudes = [];

 if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
   amplitudes[i] = eval(matches[i]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Your solution works. However, based on general feedback I made a few cosmetic changes and changed the server side to send javascript arrays. Hence I accepted ThiefMasters suggestions. Thanks for the answer anyways, cheers!

Comment: Totally acceptable! The server-side solution is concise and requires relatively few changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try using JSON to pass a javascript object directly from the server, compared to just returning a string. Almost every server side language supports JSON encoding/decoding in some form.

http://www.json.org/